# The permissions granted to user ' are insufficient for performing this operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I'm trying to deploy my report but I receive this error. How do I resolve it?

> The permissions granted to user ' are insufficient for performing this
>   operation

Comment: ask your DBA/SYSADMIN to grant your user access :)

Answer (score 0):

Access is set to private by the Admin. Ask the Admin to grant user access. This should solve your problem.